# Asp.Net: Pager in Usercontrol not paging

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, pager

I have a listview control and a datapager control in a ascx page, this is then embedded in the aspx page.

When my page loads the records come up, and the page numbers appear in the pager, however, when I click on any of the page numbers, the page is always blank, no records.

Are there any known issues with the pager in a usercontrol?

Any advice appreciated.

Regards
Melt

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem today. Your question is not very clear, tho i can maybe give a hint by telling you that you have to databind again when your page reloads.

Comment: Hi, I just tried that using the following code in the Page_load of the ascx page, but it hasn't worked, records are still not being returned when I click the page numbers

this.ListView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
this.ListView1.DataBind();

also tried

this.ListView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
this.ListView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 1):

the problem that when using user control in list view and datapager the user control initialized before rendering listview itemdataBound and thats wy you get the blank page
all you have to do is to add  public Reinitialize() method that contain the all the initialization of the user control